# Combinatorial Proof for $\binom{3n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to prove the following equality:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{k+l} = \binom{3n}{n}$

This is what I have so far:

$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{k+l} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k} \sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{l} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k+l}$

$\implies 2^{n} \cdot 2^{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k+l}$

$\implies 2^{2n} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k+l}$

I got stuck here, and I'm having trouble manipulating the second term. I would appreciate any help on this proof!

Comment: Vandermonde twice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a combinatorial proof:

Let $X$ be a set of $3n$ elements. Let's count the number of subsets of $X$ that have exactly $n$ elements. This is of course $\binom{3n}{n}$. However, here's another way to count them that yields your LHS:

Decompose $X$ into three disjoint subsets $X=X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3$ such that $|X_i|=n$ for $i=1,2,3$. A subset $U\subseteq X$ now corresponds to a triple of subsets $U_i\subseteq X_i$ for $i=1,2,3$. When $U$ has $n$ elements, we have $|U_3|=n-k-l$ for $k=|U_1|$ and $l=|U_2|$. Hence, counting all the triples $U_1,U_2,U_3$ that yield $n$ element subsets $U\subseteq X$ we get
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{l=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{n-k-l}.
$$
Since $\binom{n}{n-k-l}=\binom{n}{k+l}$ (by considering complements in $X_3$), this proves your identity.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call the sum of the given series as $S$.
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{k+l}$$
For the inner summation,$\binom{n}{k}$ is a constant and can be moved outside. We are left with:
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \sum_{l=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{k+l}$$

We first need to focus on how to find the value of the sum $\sum_{l=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{k+l}$. Call it $S_1$ for now.

To do so, we can apply a bit of Binomial Theorem.
We know that:
$$(1+x)^n = 1 + \binom{n}{1}x + ... + \binom{n}{k}x^k + \binom{n}{k+1}x^{k+1} + ... + \binom{n}{n}x^n$$
We can also once again write the series in reverse:
$$(x+1)^n = x^n + \binom{n}{1}x^{n-1} + ... + \binom{n}{n-1}x + \binom{n}{n}$$

If you notice carefully, when we multiply out the above two Binomial sequences, all of the terms of the sequence $S_1$ appear as *coefficients* of $x^{n+k}$, i.e. the sequence
$$S_1 = \sum_{l=0}^{n}  \binom{n}{n-l} \binom{n}{k+l} = \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{k+1}\binom{n}{1} + ... + \binom{n}{k+n}\binom{n}{n} $$
is nothing but the coefficient of $x^{n+k}$ in $(1+x)^{2n}$ = $\binom{2n}{n+k}$

In fact, we have discovered a useful result known as the [Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) which states that in general:
$$\binom{m+n}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{r-k}$$

Now that we have figured out $S_1$, $S$ reduces to:
$$S = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{2n}{n+k}$$

Rewriting $\binom{n}{k}$ as $\binom{n}{n-k}$ and applying Vandermonde again, we finally get:
$$S = \binom{3n}{2n} = \binom{3n}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} \binom{n}{k+l} &=& [x^0]: \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{n}{l} x^{-k-l} (1+x)^n \\
&=& [x^0]: \left(1+ \frac{1}{x} \right)^{2n} (1+x)^n \\
&=& [x^{2n}]:  (1+x)^{3n} = \binom{3n}{n}.\\
\end{eqnarray*}